# String::push_back() does not push back

Tags: c++, string, push-back

I am currently writing a infix to postfix converter. It works pretty well except I have problems adding the rest of the Stack to the postfix. The stack is a

```
vector<char>
```

and the postfix is a String. After I'm done reading everything I try the following:

```
while (!stack.empty()) {
    postfix.push_back(stack.back());
    stack.pop_back();
}
```

But there is nothing appended. I even tried it with Debug-mode and it seems fine, but nothing gets appended.

```
std::cout << postfix.c_str();
```

Leaves out the last operator from the stack. I even tried to save it temporary, but it does not get pushed.

I can not post all four files in pastebin because of the limit. I use Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate and there are no errors, just no character appended.

Comment: What do you mean by nothing is appended? `cout << postfix` doesn't display anything? Or are you attempting to evaluate the contents of postfix in some other way? Give sample input, provide more code, etc etc etc

Comment: add a sample code that reflects the behavior

Comment: This works for me. Can you post a full program that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Tried on VS2010 and all fine.

Comment: If I input "123+123" the Postfix result is: "123,123" (I use ',' as Delimiter). If I input "123+123+123" the Postfix is "123,123,+123", so the last Plus is missing at the end.

Comment: That sounds like a problem with your implementation, not with the `push_back()` function.

Comment: By full program I meant that this should compilable on its own. I tried to stub out all your definitions, but I don't know what all these types are. Use a pastebin if it's too big.

Comment: Pastebin to Code:
http://pastebin.com/SCwH8BZi (Only added <cstdio> for debugging)
http://pastebin.com/QNcGcrpR
http://pastebin.com/dWePCFjR
http://pastebin.com/kMCr2Uk0

Comment: How do you know what's in stack before you execute your loop? Rule of thumb: it is *much* more likely that a bug is in your code than the standard library.

Answer (score 1):

The way you're printing out that string is needlessly complicated - and possibly wrong. If you replace

```
std::cout << postfix.c_str();
```

with

```
std::cout << postfix;
```

You will then see what's really in the string, *even if it contains embedded null characters*.

Since you are using '\0' as an error indicator but not checking for it you are likely to have embedded nulls. And by using c_str() you are explicitly asking for the string to be truncated at the first null.